# Convert date time string to date

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

MS Access Table January2015 has a txndate field with the string "2015-01-01 11:48:00"

The field type is text.

The string needs to be converted to date/time i.e. it should appear in the same format but as a time.

Running this query:
SELECT Format(datevalue(txndate), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss") FROM January2015;

gives the output:
01-01-2015 00:00:00
(the time part is being ignored).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your desired result with one `Format()` instead of two.

```sql
SELECT Format(CDate(txndate),"dd-mm-yyyy hh:nn:ss") AS Expr1
FROM January2015;
```

Actually `Format()` will accept your *ymd* date string without the need to first convert it to Date/Time, so you could eliminate `CDate()` if you prefer.

```sql
SELECT Format(txndate,"dd-mm-yyyy hh:nn:ss") AS Expr1
FROM January2015;
```

Note however the datatype of that calculated field will be text, not Date/Time because `Format()` always returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT Format(DateValue(txndate),"dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & Format(TimeValue(txndate),"hh:nn:ss") AS Expr1
FROM January2015;